# code for space bar function, in Tibetan lang(instead of using gap, use" ་ " (ཚེག) by using space bar key board) in richtextbox

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

can anyone  kindly give me a some suggestion on my project and My project  problem is that

1. I am switching the language keyboard using "ctrl + shift"
2. when I use  English language, "space bar" is using as  space/gap between the words as usual. But once i changed/switch to my language Tibetan , "space bar " has to come as " ་ "      in Tibetan  instead. Unfortunately its not coming as " ་ " and its same as English and coming as a gap/space and nothing was changing.
3. For this app i am using WPF RichTextBox of Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 as I attached below.

Therefore , It would be very great and kind of you if you can give me a hand on this project from your busy schedules using some codes. and i am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and its tools. with many thanks - verena

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect you need something like this for the KeyPress event handler of the text box.

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Space)
    {
        if (CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture == CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("bo-CN")
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText(" ་ ");
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks  patchandthat for the great reply, can you please give me little more details on your codes if you don't mind, do we need to declare a context called "CultureInfo" as a variable??? because i couldnt find any context for this from the in-build functions. With many thanks -Verena

Comment: You will need to include the System.Globilization namespace to use the CultureInfo class.  `using System.Globilization`

Comment: i used ur code, but "་"will be appearing at the end of whole words/lines/ para, can u plss give me some more codes by using WPF richtextbox if you don't mind, bcoz rit now i couldnt upload my images as i need to get some reputations. so help me - verena

Comment: if i used Windows Form Application, that "་"ཚེག problem will be solving, but i will get one more problem thts on  "line Break", when we  start to get new line,"gap or "་"ཚེག will be coming before starting the words of next new line or new para.